# Adding space between two radio buttons of h:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, whitespace, selectoneradio

In JSF 2.0 I have below

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{StageGate.sketchesSG002006Decision}" onclick="validateMyRadioButton()" id="radio26">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Accepted" itemLabel="Accepted" id="accepted"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Rejected" itemLabel="Rejected" id="rejected"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I get output as

```
O Accepted  O Rejected
          ^^
```

What I want is add space between two radio button so that output would be

```
O Accepted           O Rejected
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried adding `&nbsp;` between two radio button however it is not working. I am getting radio button on next line.

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{StageGate.sketchesSG002006Decision}" onclick="validateMyRadioButton()" id="radio26">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Accepted" itemLabel="Accepted" id="accepted"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Rejected" itemLabel="Rejected" id="rejected"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Any idea how this can be done?

HTML generated without `&nbsp;` is

```
<table id="radio26">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio26" id="radio26:0" value="Accepted" onclick="validateMyRadioButton()" /><label for="radio26:0"> Accepted</label></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="radio26" id="radio26:1" value="Rejected" onclick="validateMyRadioButton()" /><label for="radio26:1"> Rejected</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I add `&nbsp` one space is generated before `<table id="radio26">` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer, I don't know anything about JSF, so the following is based on my experience of ASP.NET and adding spaces in there.  If this is wildly incorrect, please let me know, and I will remove immediately...

Try adding the space to the item label, updating...

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="Accepted" itemLabel="Accepted" id="accepted"/>
```

To...

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="Accepted" itemLabel="Accepted &nbsp; &nbsp;" id="accepted"/>
```

It **might** need to be escaped itself into...

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="Accepted" itemLabel="Accepted &amp;nbsp; &amp;nbsp;" id="accepted"/>
```

**UPDATE**

As the OP says in the comments, this will extend the link.

Looks like you should be able to set a CSS class to the parent object with something like...

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="myRadioCtrl" ... >
```

And then in your style / CSS have something like...

```
.myRadioCtrl span { padding-right: 10px; }
```

Comment: `Accepted &nbsp; &nbsp;` working, but it makes white space as link for Accepted which is bad :(

Comment: @Fahim, is it possible (as I say, I know nothing about JSF) to have something like `itemLabelStyle="padding-right:20px;"` or something like that?

Comment: @Fahim, or can you set a `class` to the `selectOneRadio` and format it that way?

Comment: The exact styling is-
<style type="text/css">
 .selectRadio label {margin-right: 30px;}
</style>

<p:selectOneRadio value="#{myBean.myVar}" styleClass="selectRadio">

Answer (score 3):

Just thought id share my answer... after inspecing the page with firebug i ended up with the following

JSF:

```
   <h:panelGroup id="search-options" layout="block" styleClass="radioButtonSpace">
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{searchEngineController.reportSearch}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="CEPIS Search" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="Report Search" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

CSS:

```
.radioButtonSpace table tbody td {padding-right:50px;}
```

Comment: This works well. I used class="radiobuttonSpace" in a surrounding div and it did the trick. If you want to keep the buttons and labels together you can do: .radioButtonSpace table tbody td:nth-child(even) {padding-right:10px;}

Answer (score -1):

I was having difficulties with this. Applying Style did not work for me when I did it on h:selectOneRadio, however it worked when applied in panelgroup wrapping around it.

Comment: Show code please since wrapping a panelgroup around the selectoneradio won't help the individual radiobuttons. And wrapping it around each of them is impossible

Answer (score -2):

Nothing of these answers worked for me, but like this works perfectly:

.ui-selectoneradio label{ padding-right: 10px !important; }

This is in case using primefaces

Comment: Question was about h:selectOneRadio.